# Updated some cygwin packages and wget stopped working

Tags: linux, cygwin, wget

When I run `wget <URL>`, it returns without downloading the specified URL and doesn't produce any errors.  This occurred after I updated the packages using `setup-x8x_64 --no-admin` over the weekend.

I suspect this has something to do with updating cygwin while having xterms open.  I attempted to reinstall the wget package, and uninstall and install the wget package, neither worked.  None of the options do anything either (e.g., `wget --help`), they all just return to the commandline.

Comment: Try reinstalling the cygwin package. Probably also bash and perhaps mintty, while you're at it.

Comment: run `strace wget` it should highlight which dll is causing the problem

Comment: "updating cygwin while having xterms open" How did you manage that? The install halts if you have any cygwin programs running.

Comment: I ran "strace wget" and an error window popped up with, "The procedure entry point strverscmp could not be located in the dynamic link library cygwin1.dll". Running a simple "setup-x86_64.exe --no-admin" and selecting the "cygwin" package to reinstall solved my problem.   you!

Comment: Now I'm reinstalling bash and mintty to be safe.  Thank you!  I was given a fish and taught to fish better for myself.  You guys rock!